# Node.js and Express session handling - Back button problem

Tags: session, node.js, express

I have a restricted area '/dashboard' in my Express application. I use a very small function to limit the access:

```
app.get('/dashboard', loadUser, function(req, res){
  res.render('dashboard', {
    username: req.session.username
  });
});

function loadUser(req, res, next){
  if (req.session.auth) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
};
```

The problem is that when I logout a user by calling...

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  if (req.session) {
    req.session.auth = null;
    res.clearCookie('auth');
    req.session.destroy(function() {});
  }
  res.redirect('/login');
});
```

... the session is killed but **when I hit Back Button in my browser I got the restricted page from browser's cache. This means no GET on '/dashboard' and no user login validation.**

I tried using no-cache in meta (Jade Template) but it still doesn't work.

```
meta(http-equiv='Cache-Control', content='no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate')
meta(http-equiv='Pragma', content='no-cache')
meta(http-equiv='Expires', content='-1')
```

Anyone?

Comment: Related: [When the client gets to a page by hitting the back button, how to make it load a fresh copy instead of cached one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589771/when-the-client-gets-to-a-page-by-hitting-the-back-button-how-to-make-it-load-a/24591864#24591864)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Josh's answer sadly didn't work for me.
But after some searching I found this 
question: [What's the best way to deal with cache and the browser back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-cache-and-the-browser-back-button)

and adopted the answer there to this node.js/express problem.
You just have to change the following line

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
```

to

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

Now, everytime I use the browser back button, the page is reloaded and not cached.

*** update for express v4.x ***

```
// caching disabled for every route
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  next();
});

// otherwise put the res.set() call into the route-handler you want
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Where exactly do you add that line of code?

Comment: Try this: app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        next();
    });

Comment: @nikjohn updated the answer to include a snippet for express 4+

Comment: @pkyeck Yeah I tried `res.set` but unfortunately, I don't think there is _any_ solution for this issue. It's just completely upto the browser it looks like

Comment: @nikjohn this works perfectly, I hope you got it to work for you, thanks for the answer Phil

Comment: `res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');` line just  did my long pending work. Thank you very much :) , Happy coding .

Comment: This is only working for get endpoints. Any idea on make it working for post endpoints as well

Answer (score 8):

```
app.get('/dashboard', loadUser, function(req, res){
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.header('Expires', 'Fri, 31 Dec 1998 12:00:00 GMT');

  res.render('dashboard', {
    username: req.session.username
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Am using using Express ^4.16.3 and this worked for me as stated by @pkyeck.

I added it to my routes like this and it worked fine:

```
routes
.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        next();
          })
          .get('/login', function(req, res, next){
              .....
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is after clearing the session .. again redirect to the same route.. for example: route /sessionedpage has session variables .. after clicking logout button clear session variables by     `req.session.destroy(function() {});` after that you are tring to redirect home page ... INSTEAD of redirecting to home page.. redirect /sessionedpage (same route) ... Write if condition for /sessionedpage if(!res.sessions) then res.redirect('/home')

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply **add the following middleware** before all routes in your NodeJS app which uses **Express** back-end and a **PUG** front-end to solve this back button problem. This is the most bare-bones solution:

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

```
var forwardAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, 
    post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    if (!token) {
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/listProducts');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loading page from cache, use the below code in `app.js`,

Note: Use it before using the routers

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   next();
 });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).