# How can I prevent the browser's back button from accessing restricted information, after the user has logged out?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm Using [this example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3-mongoose-rememberme/app.js) found on github for passport local strategy with mongoose/mongodb.
The problem that I'm encountering is that when a user logs out, they can still access restricted information by hitting the back button on the browser. I'm kind of new to node.js but I would imagine that some kind of hook would need to be implemented to call the `ensureAuthenticated` function - located all the way at the very bottom of the code - before the back and forward buttons are executed. How can I prevent a user from accessing restricted information, by hitting the back button, after the user has logged out?

```
var express = require('express')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , mongodb = require('mongodb')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
  , SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
  console.log('Connected to DB');
});

// User Schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true},
  accessToken: { type: String } // Used for Remember Me
});

// Bcrypt middleware
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
        if(err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

// Password verification
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

// Remember Me implementation helper method
userSchema.methods.generateRandomToken = function () {
  var user = this,
      chars = "_!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890",
      token = new Date().getTime() + '_';
  for ( var x = 0; x < 16; x++ ) {
    var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * 62 );
    token += chars.charAt( i );
  }
  return token;
};

// Seed a user
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
// var usr = new User({ username: 'bob', email: 'bob@example.com', password: 'secret' });
// usr.save(function(err) {
//   if(err) {
//     console.log(err);
//   } else {
//     console.log('user: ' + usr.username + " saved.");
//   }
// });


// Passport session setup.
//   To support persistent login sessions, Passport needs to be able to
//   serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  Typically,
//   this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
//   the user by ID when deserializing.
//
//   Both serializer and deserializer edited for Remember Me functionality
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  var createAccessToken = function () {
    var token = user.generateRandomToken();
    User.findOne( { accessToken: token }, function (err, existingUser) {
      if (err) { return done( err ); }
      if (existingUser) {
        createAccessToken(); // Run the function again - the token has to be unique!
      } else {
        user.set('accessToken', token);
        user.save( function (err) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          return done(null, user.get('accessToken'));
        })
      }
    });
  };

  if ( user._id ) {
    createAccessToken();
  }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(token, done) {
  User.findOne( {accessToken: token } , function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


// Use the LocalStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, a username and password), and invoke a callback
//   with a user object.  In the real world, this would query a database;
//   however, in this example we are using a baked-in set of users.
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
      }
    });
  });
}));


var app = express();

// configure Express
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' })); // CHANGE THIS SECRET!
  // Remember Me middleware
  app.use( function (req, res, next) {
    if ( req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/login' ) {
      if ( req.body.rememberme ) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 2592000000; // 30*24*60*60*1000 Rememeber 'me' for 30 days
      } else {
        req.session.cookie.expires = false;
      }
    }
    next();
  });
  // Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
  // persistent login sessions (recommended).
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../public'));
});
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  var users = User.find();
  console.log(users);
  res.send(users);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { user: req.user, message: req.session.messages });
});

// POST /login
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
//   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
//   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
//
//   curl -v -d "username=bob&password=secret" http://127.0.0.1:3000/login
//   
/***** This version has a problem with flash messages
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
*/

// POST /login
//   This is an alternative implementation that uses a custom callback to
//   acheive the same functionality.
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) {
      req.session.messages =  [info.message];
      return res.redirect('/login')
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});


// Simple route middleware to ensure user is authenticated.
//   Use this route middleware on any resource that needs to be protected.  If
//   the request is authenticated (typically via a persistent login session),
//   the request will proceed.  Otherwise, the user will be redirected to the
//   login page.
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login')
}
```

**Edit**
I think I might be on to something but can't get it to work. After doing some more research,
It seems that what I need to do is prevent local cacheing. I'm attempting to do this from within my `app.configure` function:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    next();
  });
});
```

However, this does not seem to be effecting my headers.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When the client gets to a page by hitting the back button, how to make it load a fresh copy instead of cached one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589771/when-the-client-gets-to-a-page-by-hitting-the-back-button-how-to-make-it-load-a)

Comment: Also related: [Node.js and Express session handling - Back button problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096492/node-js-and-express-session-handling-back-button-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Since the browser pulls that page from cache, it doesn't matter what *you* do on that page, unless you add a JS check to see if the user is still authenticated... but that doesn't solve the problem of the page being in cache.

Reframing the problem as a cache one, I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591864/217374

It's been over a year since you asked, so I don't expect you specifically to need the answer any more, but there it is for anyone else who comes by.

Answer (score 0):

When the user navigates back in the browser, the data is shown from the local browser cache, and not requested from your server. What you can do, is to add some javascript to your logout event. That piece of js can remove sensitive pages from the browser history.
You can work with window.history to manipulate the browser history.
Have a look in [this guide for manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and the [window.history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history) .

Not sure if this is bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your html (or view files)

```
meta(http-equiv='Cache-Control', content='no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate')
meta(http-equiv='Pragma', content='no-cache')
meta(http-equiv='Expires', content='-1')
```

Comment: Meta tags are ignored for http / https sources. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824848/is-meta-http-equiv-value-cache-control-is-not-supported