# Node js session destroy does not redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writting login system but when i click logout button website is opening same page.

```
<form action="out" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item py-3 pr-5">logout</button>
</form>
```

server.js:

```
app.post('/out', function(request, response) {
    request.session.destroy();
    response.redirect('/');
});
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/chat.html'));
    } else {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
    }
});
```

Website every time opening chat.html but If I full refresh the site, web site opening index.html.

Comment: console `request.session.loggedin` and check what u get after hit logout button

Answer (score 2):

```
app.post('/out', function(request, response) {
    request.session.destroy(err => {
        if(err) {
             console.log(err)
         }else{
             response.redirect('/signup');
         }
    });
});
```

U can try this. First destroy the session then call a callback function inside there check if there is any issue in destroying session if not then redirect

Comment: This is the right way to do it because `request.session.destroy()` is asynchronous and unless you wait until its done before you redirect, you run the risk of the redirect getting processed by the browser and the new incoming request arrived BEFORE the session has been fully destroyed.

Comment: yes i forget to mention the `asynchronous ` word Thanks @jfriend00

Comment: Still same.. :(

Comment: I solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096492/node-js-and-express-session-handling-back-button-problem