# Browser back button showing the page from cache?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, browser-cache

When I logout from wordpress website, it will be redirected to the login page. But the issue is, if I hit the browser back button, It will show the previous page, which need the authorization. I know, the page is being loaded from the browser cache and no interaction with the server is happening. But I need to force the page to reload if the user hit the browser back button.

I did check the header and I could find the following

```
Cache-Control:  no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

I have also tried by adding the following meta tags and it didn't work.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Please help

Comment: http://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history that can help =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have tried by setting header like below and it worked like a charm!

```
header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate,
        max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
      );
```

Comment: And which one of those helped you?

Answer (score -1):

Tried lot of solutions but only the below one worked out . Added below java script in the logout page.
All the other solutions will work fine in browsers other than IE.

```
window.onunload = function() {
    window.location.href = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/logout.jsp";
};
```