# Laravel: On clicking laravel back button page with old input and errors is getting displayed

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 application which uses a form to register a user. When the user submits the form, if there are any validation errors, the app will return to same page with input and the validation errors. And if the submission was successful the users will be redirected to another page.

Now if the user presses the browser back button from the submission successful page they are taken back to the page with the old validation errors and input.

I am aware that this is a common problem with other sites also. Is there a way around this using Laravel or Javascript?

Comment: So the user is send back to the page with **old** validation errors and input? So it is something that happened before? So I assume it's normal behaviour. Wouldn't a simple redirect work?

Comment: I think that is normal. The back button works with browser cache, it does not send request to the server. And if you prefer not to show the previous page on click of back button, then just disable browser cache. Then clicking back button will keep the user on the same page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088616/browser-back-button-showing-the-page-from-cache

Comment: @Loko Yeah the errors which occured just before the successful submission. Redirect? From the registration page?

Comment: @Michel, blackpla9ue : I have disabled the cache for the login and logout pages and logout and login workflow is fine. But I don't think it is a good idea to disable cache on all the pages.

Comment: @tav I'd say a redirect right after the validation(if there is any) passes and the form is submitting. Dont submit the form immediatly to the target page. Let the form submit to the same page you're on and if the register is good, redirect it to the target page.